# Java Pattern Matcher Multiple Optimizing

Tags: java, regex

I have to prepare a program wheremultiple regular expression are used.
Below is the program but for every new element I have to initialize new Pattern and Matcher. Is there any optimized way which I can use in this program or a loop which I can use in this.
Currently in the program its reading file and assigning all the XML tags in the string. The file is having multiple tags which I have to initialize and print in CSV format and files are having a huge amount of data like in GBs.
Is there any way to optimize below code.

Regex Program:

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package javaapplication1;

/**
*
* @author ????
*/
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class JavaApplication1 {

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String oldContent = "";
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        FileWriter writer = null;
        File fileToBeModified = new File("C:\\Documents\\audit.log");
        String str = "";
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToBeModified));
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
            String st;
            while ((st=in.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(st);
                output.append('\n');
            }
            str = output.toString();
            in.close();
        }
        catch (Exception fx) {
        } 
        String usr = "";
        String origin = "";
        String dt = "";
        String operation = "";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<AuditEntry>(.*\\R)*?<\\/AuditEntry>");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        while (m.find()) {
            Pattern e = Pattern.compile("<User>(.*)</User>");
            Matcher f = e.matcher(m.group(0));
            while(f.find())
            {
                usr = f.group(1);
            }
            Pattern g = Pattern.compile("<Origin>(.*)</Origin>");
            Matcher h = g.matcher(m.group(0));
            while(h.find())
            {
                origin = h.group(1);
            }
            Pattern i = Pattern.compile("<DateTime.*\">(.*)</DateTime>");
            Matcher j = i.matcher(m.group(0));
            while(j.find())
            {
                dt = j.group(1);
            }
            Pattern k = Pattern.compile("Operation=\"([a-zA-z]+)\"");
            Matcher l = k.matcher(m.group(0));
            while(l.find())
            {
                operation = l.group(1);
            }
            System.out.println(usr+","+origin+"," +dt+ ","+operation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: create a hashmap of <String, Pattern>, where String is same identifier, now in your main method initialise the hashmap, and use it throughout your code.

Comment: Don't parse markup with regex.

Comment: I cannot understand why people downvote a question that is obviously from a programming beginner, provides a clear question and well formatted source code where somebody already tried a lot to get a solution. (Sorry for offtopic.)

Answer (score 0):

The hashmap mentioned in the comment sounds suitable but less readable. I'd prefer the "method" approach:

```
    private String getMatch(final String pattern, final String txt) {
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
    String result = null;
    while (m.find()) {
        result = m.group(1);
    }
    return result;
}

public void xxx() {
    //...
    while (m.find()) {
        final String txt = m.group(0);
        origin = getMatch("<Origin>(.*)</Origin>", txt);
        usr = getMatch("<User>(.*)</User>", txt);
        // ...
    }
}
```